# Tell f2py to skip a function

Tags: python, unit-testing, fortran, f2py

I am using f2py to compile a Fortran library such that I can import it in python so that I can easily create unit tests. However, one of the functions in the module uses an allocatable array to read a matrix from a file (the size of the matrix is not know until it is read). Unfortunately, f2py does not support allocatable arrays so compilation fails.

Can I tell f2py to ignore only the problematic function using a comment in the module?

I know it is possible to `skip` a list of functions specified at compile time, but I was hoping there was a solution that could be implemented in the source file, like the `!f2py` comments that modify how parameters are treated by f2py.

Comment: To perform partial wrapping, you can use `.pyf` files. The process is the following: Use `-m module_name -h module_file.f90` to generate a default `.pyf` file. Edit the `.pyf` file to keep only what you want to expose to Python. Compile the Fortran code and the interface with `f2py -c`. By listing both `.pyf` and `.f90` files, the process should take the wrapper properly. I tested succesfully on a small sample. Let me know if it works, so that I can post a proper answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the f2py docs [here](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/f2py/usage.html) it says that you can skip a function by doing this:

```
  f2py -h <filename.pyf> <options> <fortran files>   \
      [[ only: <fortran functions>  : ]                \
       [ skip: <fortran functions>  : ]]...            \
      [<fortran files> ...]
```

where `skip:""` can be used to skip any function you dont want to execute.

Comment: I saw that, but I was hoping there was a solution that could be implemented in the source file, like the `!f2py` comments that modify how parameters are treated by f2py, so that I wouldn't need to do it do it when the module is compiled

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean, you might want to edit your question to specify this. I'll look more in it and give results.

Comment: This answer is probably the best option. As I think about it more, there is not a lot to be gained by specifying in the Fortran file that a function should be skipped instead of in the Makefile where I call `f2py`.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no (documented) way to add the `only:` and `skip:` options to distutils.